# Azure put_block_blob_from_path(): Avoid timeout error

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am uploading a 60 GB file using Python and azure-storage. I get a timeout error (read timeout=65) more often than not:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myaccount.blob...', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=65)
```

The code:

```
bs = BlobService(account_name=storage_account, account_key =account_key)

bs.put_block_blob_from_path(
  container_name = my_container,
  blob_name = azure_blobname,
  file_path = localpath,
  x_ms_blob_content_type = "text/plain",
  max_connections=5
)
```

Is there something I can do to increase the timeout or otherwise fix this issue? put_block_blob_from_path() doesn't seem to have a timeout parameter.

I am using an older version of azure-storage (0.20.0). That's so we don't have to rewrite our code (put_block_blob_from_path no longer exists) and so we avoid the inevitable downtime as we install the new version, switch the code over, and deal with whatever crap is related to installing the new version over the old version. Is this timeout an issue that has been solved in newer versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're a few things you could try:

- **Increase the timeout**: `BlobService` constructor has a `timeout` parameter, default value of which is `65 seconds`. You can try to increase that. I believe the max timeout value you can specify is `90 seconds`. So your code would be:

```
    bs = BlobService(account_name=storage_account, account_key=account_key, timeout=90)
```

- **Reduce "max_connections"**: `max_connections` property defines the maximum number of parallel threads in which upload is happening. Since you're uploading a 60GB file, SDK automatically splits that file in 4MB chunks and upload 5 chunks (based on your current value) in parallel. You can try by reducing this value and see if that gets rid of the timeout error you're receiving.
- **Manually implement `put_block` and `put_block_list`**: By default the SDK splits the blob in 4MB chunks and upload these chunks. You can try by using `put_block` and `put_block_list` methods in the SDK where you're reducing the chunk size from 4MB to a smaller value (say 512KB or 1MB).

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware that I could set timeout in BlobService(). I'll try this out and report back how it went.

Comment: Setting timeout on BlobService() did the trick. I set it to 300 and didn't get an error.